# Sum TD in one TR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i sum values from td input in one TR?

```
<table>
    <tr class="here">
        <td><input type="text" class="one" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="two" value="4"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="three" value="5"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="four" value="3"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="sum"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="five" value="2"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="here">
        <td><input type="text" class="one" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="two" value="4"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="three" value="5"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="four" value="3"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="sum"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="five" value="2"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="here">
        <td><input type="text" class="one" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="two" value="6"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="three" value="4"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="four" value="2"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="sum"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="five" value="2"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="here">
        <td><input type="text" class="one" value="5" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="two" value="2"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="three" value="3"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="four" value="8"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="sum"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="five" value="4"  /></td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TFM3K/)

I can sum all values with function .each but how to make this for each tr, not td?

I would like sum values from input with class TWO and class THREE and class FOUR and add this to input with class SUM in same TR.

For my example should be:

```
2 4 5 3 **12** 2 // 4+5+3
2 4 5 3 **12** 2 // 4+5+3
2 6 4 2 **12** 2 // 6+4+2
5 2 3 8 **13** 4 // 2+3+8
```

Comment: Please do not link to external resources that can vanish, thus making your question useless to others. Include a sample as part of your question.

Comment: Have you made your own attempt?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code should look like this.

You need to iterate over the `td` with the particular class in question and sum up the values. Then assign that value to the input that you were referring to.

```
$('tr.here').each(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('.two, .three, .four', this).each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    });

    $('.sum', this).val(sum);
})
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TFM3K/1/)**

Comment: Why would anybody downvote this answer? It functions exactly as the OP has described.

Comment: That is the context selector.. You want to only sum up the values inside the class of the `current row` but not all of them together.. This is same as `$(this).find('.two, .three, .four')` .. Check the docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Comment: @user2565589: Use `.find()` instead. It's more intuitive, as evidenced by the fact that the code in the answer needed to be explained.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
$('tr.here').each(function () {
    var sum = parseFloat($(this).find('.two').val()) + parseFloat($(this).find('.three').val()) + parseFloat($(this).find('.four').val());

    $(this).find('.sum').val(sum);
})
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/TFM3K/5/)